# re.sub() with a non-empty substitution eats up following character in Python

Tags: python, regex, character, outlook-addin, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to separate a word with two adjacent vowels by inserting a non-alphabetic group of characters. When I use `re.sub()` with a non-empty substitution, the result shows the insertion but the insertion seems to have "eaten up" the following character.

Here's an example"

```
import = re

word = "aorta"

re.sub('(?<=[AEOUaeouy])(?:[aeoui])', '[=]', word)
#actual output => 'a[=]r[=]ta'
#expected output => 'a[=]or[=]ta'
```

Why is the character following the insertion eaten up?

Comment: You wanted a lookahead, not a non-capturing group -  `(?:[aeoui])` > `(?=[aeoui])`. BTW, why is `a[=]or[=]ta` expected?

Comment: Omg, you're right! Thanks! If you use this as a response I will accept it.

Comment: I think your expected result is `a[=]orta`, right? `[AEOUaeouy]` does not contain `r`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (a non-consuming pattern that only checks for the presence of some chars without actually adding them to the match value), not a non-capturing group (a consuming pattern that puts the matched chars into the match value that get replaced with `re.sub`).

Use

```
import re
word = "aorta"
print(re.sub('([AEOUaeouy])(?=[aeoui])', r'\1[=]', word))
# => a[=]orta
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/DNuWsx).

Note: if you wish to get `'a[=]or[=]ta'`, add `r` to the lookbehind character class, `[AEOUaeouy]` => `[AEOUaeouyr]`.

**Details**

- `([AEOUaeouy])` - Group 1: any one of the chars defined in the pattern
- `(?=[aeoui])` - a position that is followed with the chars in the character class
- `\1` - in the replacement pattern, inserts the value captured with Group 1.